# Which investment do you choose? Same expected return but differing variances and correlation

Tags: capm, expected-return

Let's say you have two investments, A and B. Both A and B have the same expected return. However A has low variance and is not correlated with any other investments. Whereas B has high variance and has correlation with other investments.

Which would you pick? How would you make the decision?

Comment: You might get a better answer if you include some hard numbers in your question.  Terms like 'no correlation' and 'high variance' are relative

Comment: Even without adding numbers it should be clear to you that A is very attractive to an investor who likes mean and dislikes variance of returns. Agree?